# apt upgrade error after using ubuntu 23.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

```
Cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=6.2.0-27-generic..........(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8188fu: 1.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-27-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8188fu/1.0/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-27-generic/x86_64 succeeded for 8812au 8812au 8812au virtualbox virtualbox
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-27-generic/x86_64 failed for rtl8188fu(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.2.0-27-generic
 linux-headers-generic
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
 linux-generic-hwe-22.04
 linux-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-27-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Don't post logvomit ("here's my guess at all the data - you figure it out").
Do not post the whole log file! 99+% of the log entries are not of interest. Use an editor (on  a copy of the file), and keep ONLY the error entries, plus 2 lines before and 2 lines after. You should end up with a max of 50 lines, and probably fewer than 50. Edit your question to add information,  and use the formatting tools. Comments are for US to ask YOU to improve your Question, to help us help you.

Comment: You should get rid of `rtl8188fu` DKMS module which now fails

Comment: i removed rtl8188fu but im still getting error.
cant update, install anything